# iOS JSON Parse Return null

Tags: ios, xcode, json

I have searched online for solution toward this problem, but the result that is always returned to me is null.

This is the following string that I received from a web. Everything seems to work fine. However, when I were to convert this string into an array then the result returned is null.

The code:

```
- (void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection {
NSLog(@"connectionDidFinishLoading");
NSLog(@"Succeeded! Received %d bytes of data",[self.responseData length]);

// String
NSString *responseString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:self.responseData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSLog(@"%@", responseString);

NSDictionary *resultsDictionary = [responseString objectFromJSONString];
NSLog(@"%@", resultsDictionary); // Returns null
```

}

The result:
    [{"cid":"382595836","name":"\u514d\u7a0e\u5e97\u4e13\u5356\u54c1"},{"cid":"382595837","name":"\u9650\u91cf\u7248\u9999\u6c34"},{"cid":"380837083","name":"\u5973\u58eb\u7cbe\u88c5"},{"cid":"380837082","name":"\u7537\u58eb\u7cbe\u88c5"},{"cid":"61540749","name":"\u7b80\u88c5\u5973\u7528\u9999\u6c34"},{"cid":"24213689","name":"\u7b80\u88c5\u7537\u7528\u9999\u6c34"},{"cid":"25541561","name":"Q\u9999\u5973\u58eb"},{"cid":"25541841","name":"Q\u9999\u7537\u58eb"}]

May anyone provide me a way to think through this.

Thanks.

Comment: Your JSON data is an array (not an object or dictionary) since it starts and ends with brackets (instead of curly braces).

Comment: I'm sorry all. The person who programmed the server called me and said that there was some unwanted strings before the character. This resulted in the error.

Comment: check my answer.. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13524871/json-parsing-on-iphone-sdk/13525096#13525096

Answer (score 1):

try this

`NSMutableData *responseData;`  // use in .h  class

use this function in use in .m  class

```
-(void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)data
{
    NSLog(@"connection did receive data");
    [responseData appendData:data];
    NSString *responseString = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:[responseData bytes]];
    NSLog(@"%@",responseString);
}
- (void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection
{
    NSLog(@"Succeeded! Received %d bytes of data", [responseData length]);
}
```

Comment: The problem isn't that. The problem is converting the json it into json data. I receive the string perfectly. but when I convert it to json data it returns (null).

Comment: your json is invail , plz remove this line 2012-11-30 14:29:52.779 com.JSON.Product[1979:c07

Comment: vaild json [{"cid":"382595836","name":"\u514d\u7a0e\u5e97\u4e13\u5356\u54c1"},{"cid":"382595837","name":"\u9650\u91cf\u7248\u9999\u6c34"},{"cid":"380837083","name":"\u5973\u58eb\u7cbe\u88c5"},{"cid":"380837082","name":"\u7537\u58eb\u7cbe\u88c5"},{"cid":"61540749","name":"\u7b80\u88c5\u5973\u7528\u9999\u6c34"},{"cid":"24213689","name":"\u7b80\u88c5\u7537\u7528\u9999\u6c34"},{"cid":"25541561","name":"Q\u9999\u5973\u58eb"},{"cid":"25541841","name":"Q\u9999\u7537\u58eb"}]

Answer (score 0):

Use below code. The code will work on ios 5.0 and later.

```
NSArray* list = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:self.responseData options:kNilOptions
                          error:&error];
```

I did this. It's working fine for me. Can you try below one logic.

```
NSString *filePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"demo" ofType:@"json"];
NSData *myData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:filePath];
NSError *error;
id json = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:myData options:kNilOptions error:&error];
NSArray *list = (NSArray *)json;
```

Comment: Its working now. It was the server error. There seems to be some unwanted strings, but was not shown in the log.

Answer (score -1):

The `objectFromJSONString` will return `nil` if the string you're passing in isn't valid JSON.

I checked this

`[{"cid":"382595836","name":"\u514d\u7a0e\u5e97\u4e13\u5356\u54c1"},{"cid":"382595837","name":"\u9650\u91cf\u7248\u9999\u6c34"},{"cid":"380837083","name":"\u5973\u58eb\u7cbe\u88c5"},{"cid":"380837082","name":"\u7537\u58eb\u7cbe\u88c5"},{"cid":"61540749","name":"\u7b80\u88c5\u5973\u7528\u9999\u6c34"},{"cid":"24213689","name":"\u7b80\u88c5\u7537\u7528\u9999\u6c34"},{"cid":"25541561","name":"Q\u9999\u5973\u58eb"},{"cid":"25541841","name":"Q\u9999\u7537\u58eb"}] 2012-11-30 14:29:52.779 com.JSON.Product[1979:c07]`

in [**JSONLint**](http://jsonlint.com/) it shows it is an **invalid JSON**.

Comment: [{"cid":"382595836","name":"\u514d\u7a0e\u5e97\u4e13\u5356\u54c1"},{"cid":"382595837","name":"\u9650\u91cf\u7248\u9999\u6c34"},{"cid":"380837083","name":"\u5973\u58eb\u7cbe\u88c5"},{"cid":"380837082","name":"\u7537\u58eb\u7cbe\u88c5"},{"cid":"61540749","name":"\u7b80\u88c5\u5973\u7528\u9999\u6c34"},{"cid":"24213689","name":"\u7b80\u88c5\u7537\u7528\u9999\u6c34"},{"cid":"25541561","name":"Q\u9999\u5973\u58eb"},{"cid":"25541841","name":"Q\u9999\u7537\u58eb"}]

Comment: It's valid JSON if the characters after the last closing bracket are removed. It's not clear to me whether this is the cause of the problem or just an artifact of copying the JSON data out of the debugger into the question.

Comment: @user288231: Please fix the question accordingly as it's currently causing unnecessary confusion.